# Symfony2: Is possible to get the user object in app_dev.php

Tags: symfony

Hello I would like to call a task/function that must be performed always in any page of our site.
I dont know if its possible to do it in the app_dev.php or where you can recommend me I should do it.

I though on create a class and define it as a service, but I really dont know how to start that service. We need that service to start always, its doesnt matter what page the user visits, we need first to run that service and after the controller.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the frontend controller (app.php or app_dev.php), the application hasn't been booted yet, so you can't get that level of control. Instead, what you want to do is create an event listener and listen to the [`kernel.request` event](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/internals.html#kernel-request-event). From that doc page:

> The goal of this event is to either return a Response object immediately or setup variables so that a Controller can be called after the event. Any listener can return a Response object via the setResponse() method on the event. In this case, all other listeners won't be called.

In order to set up a service to listen to that event, you'd declare it something like this:

```
# services.yml
foo_request_listener:
  class: FooVendor\BarBundle\EventListener\RequestEventListener
  arguments: [] # whatever dependencies your listener needs
  tags:
    - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
```

The first part (before `tags`) is just a normal service declaration. The `kernel.event_listener` tag is just saying that your service should receive the a `GetResponseEvent` object via the `onKernelRequest` method when the `kernel.request` event is emitted (the method name is arbitrary, just make sure your service class implements it), which happens on every request before the controller is called.

Comment: Should I declare it like that?
services:
 kernel_listener:
  class: Bernardao\ExtraBundle\Listener
   arguments:
   tags:
     - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
--
and my listener
<?php
namespace Bernardao\ExtraBundle\Listener;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event;
class LoginListener{
    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event){
    }
}
Im not sure about what type of event I have to declare on "onKernelRequest". Is it right GetResponseEvent?

Comment: I just found the GetResponseEvent in namespace Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event;

Ill try to work on it. Im new to stackoverflow, so not sure how im answering :-p

Comment: @Bernardao, For reference implementation of kernel request listener check [SessionListener](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/EventListener/SessionListener.php) class. Service is defined [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/session.xml#L37)